# Linking cells from different worksheets with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am having some trouble linking values between worksheets with VBA. I was able to copy the value from a newly created worksheet into my "input" worksheet, but when changing the value in the newly created worksheet, the value in the "input" sheet doesn't change. Is there anyone who could help me out with this. This is my code so far (please take notice to the 3rd to last paragraph) :

```
financing = ws.Range("F2").Value
compName = ws.Range("F3").Value
fortnr = compName & "-" & financing

lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Cells(lastRow, "B") = financing
ws.Cells(lastRow, "C") = compName

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Copy After:=Worksheets("Template")
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Name = compName & "-" & financing
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(compName & "-" & financing).Visible = xlSheetVisible

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template (2)").Name = "Template"

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(fortnr).Select

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(fortnr).Range("B3").Value = financing
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(fortnr).Range("B4").Value = compName

ws.Cells(lastRow, "D") = Sheets(fortnr).Range("B6").Value
ws.Cells(lastRow, "E") = Sheets(fortnr).Range("B7").Value

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Cells(lastRow, 1), Address:="", 
SubAddress:= _
"'" & fortnr & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:="Check"                                  

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Sheets(compName & "-" & financing).Range("A1"), 
"", Sheets("INPUT").Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:="Back to Input-sheet"
```

Comment: You would have to use `.Paste Link:=True` Note:if the cells are in different workbooks, both workbook would have to be open. If you don't want to use `Link=True`, then you would have to place your code in a worksheet change event.

Comment: Or, you could place a formula in the cell you want to keep updated e.g. `Sheet2.Range("A5").Formula= "=Sheet3!$A$1"`

Comment: Hi GMalc,
Thanks for your reply. This formula function works better, but the problem I am having is being able to link the new worksheet. Since the name of the new worksheet is constructed early in the code, fortnr = compName & "-" & financing. If i put "fortnr" in as the destination of the independent cell, it doesn't create i link when I create a new "case". it just says "=fortnr!$B$6". Any ideas how i can create this link?

Comment: Hi again Gmalc,
Figured it out, used this code: ws.Cells(lastRow, "D").Formula = "='" & fortnr & "'!$B$6"

Thanks again!